# Is there a practical difference between changing a user's shell by chsh vs. editing .bashrc?

Tags: bash, shell

I've always set my shell by either using `chsh` or `sudo vim /etc/passwd`. I recently talked to someone who instead sets his shell by adding the following to `~/.bashrc` (or presumably the rc file of whatever the default shell on the machine is): `SHELL=/bin/zsh exec /bin/zsh --login`.

Is there a practical difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 7):

The latter method doesn't *change* your shell – it just tells the old shell to run a new one.

In addition to being almost twice as slow (since you still start bash every time), it can result in some unexpected interactions:

- In some systems, batch commands like `ssh myhost "ps -ef"` will source ~/.bashrc before running the command – but your "exec zsh" line forgot to account for that, and runs an *interactive* shell no matter what. If that happens, all batch usage of SSH (including SFTP) is broken.
- In other systems, such batch commands *don't* source ~/.bashrc (or, frequently,  they do but ~/.bashrc returns early if running in batch mode) – so your "exec zsh" is never even reached. So your friend's attempt to change the shell is less effective.
- If you forget about this change, and try to edit ~/.zshrc to do the opposite (i.e. run bash), you get an endless loop.